# change background of row in table on button click in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creting a table using ng-repeat in angularjs, and i want to change background colour of row on button click.
Like on clicking yes green colour should be set and on no button red colour is set.
can somebody help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row has an ID. All you have to do is to send this ID to the function `setSelected(),` store it (in `$scope.idSelectedVote` for instance), and then check for each row if the selected ID is the same as the current one. Here is a solution(see [the documentation or ngClass, if needed](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass));

```
 $scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
       $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
    };
```

.

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)" ng-class="{selected: vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
    ...
</ul>
```

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkaYSbtKFdx1I9N0xP5E?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the Help.Using this a single click on any row will highlight the row.

Comment: if you like my answer please correct answer button click @user3415447

Comment: Thanks for the Help.Using this a single click on any row will highlight the row. I want to select a row on a single button click.Can you please help .

Comment: Please Refer this model http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/ @user3415447

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)" ng-class="

    {selected: vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
        ...
    </ul>
```

in controller

```
$scope.idSelectedVote = null;
$scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
   $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
};
```

refer:`http://plnkr.co/edit/SkaYSbtKFdx1I9N0xP5E?p=preview`

Comment: why you post my answer again